# I want to convert a String date "Sat, 03 Jul 2021 06:06:06 GMT" to a String with format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" in UTC using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help with a code?

```
function getDateTimeinUTC(inputstringdate) {

//Code to convert "Sat, 03 Jul 2021 06:06:06 GMT to a date and then use below sort of code to convert it to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm

    var DateTimeFormatter = Java.type('java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter');
    var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
    var ldt = java.time.LocalDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC);
    return ldt.format(dtf);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple code:**

```
x=new Date("Sat, 03 Jul 2021 06:06:06 GMT")

x.toISOString()
```

Example, on FF dev console:
[image]